# How can I ensure that I don't perform the same database transaction twice?

Tags: javascript, sql

I'm performing insertions on a database across the network, and I want to make sure I never try to insert data that I have already inserted.  The client is running in a web browser, using Javascript to send an XMLHttpRequest to the server containing the data to insert.  If there is an error then I must try again later - for instance, there might be a transient network error.  However, there is no way I know of that I can get a guarantee that I will be notified that an insertion succeeded, as the network might go down after the request has gone through to the server but before the reply of success can be returned.  Although this seems very unlikely to me, should it happen it would totally mess up the database as there is no way to know that certain entries should not be there.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle, . . . ?) And -- are you familiar with primary keys, unique constraints, etc.?

Comment: you need to do this in the db, not on the web

Comment: Yes, but how?  The rows being inserted are basically a log of string commands, there is no requirement that they be unique, the only requirement is that they aren't erroneously duplicated (because otherwise when the log is replayed it will result in the wrong end state.)

Comment: @dandavis revisiting this question: what if I'm concerned about any CRUD operation?  well, at least the CUD part, seems like this would be a big problem in any non-local database, of which I imagine there would be many.  ATMs come to mind... unless there is a simple way to do this, seems like any non-trivial database requires a lot of extra work to handle the possibility of a transaction "silently" succeeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the presence or absence of the data you're inserting so that if a second identical transaction comes through, it is simply ignored. Something like:

```
INSERT MyTable (Value1, Value2, Value3)
SELECT @Value1, @Value2, @Value3
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.MyTable T
      WHERE
          T.Value1 = @Value1
          AND T.Value2 = @Value2
   )
;
```

Note that this doesn't completely solve potential race conditions where two clients are trying to perform the same action at the same time--the `EXISTS` clause executes in time before the `INSERT` operation, and this can yield two clients attempting to insert. Therefore, you must either add locking such as `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` (horrible for concurrency because if the row doesn't exist it has to take a range lock which can block unrelated data inserts), or tolerate errors about duplicate keys appropriately in the client.

If it is actually okay for the data to be duplicated so long as the client sent it in, then you can accommodate that in a couple of ways:

1. Add additional columns to the table until it is unique.
2. Or, create a timestamp/serial number that is part of the transaction, and after inserting (within a database transaction) record this serial number to a table. Associate the insert with the absence of this serial number.

Developing some strategy for your client holding sent requests until they can be acked could be an additional layer of protection that simultaneously might prevent some of the duplicate tries in the first place--if you don't get an ack now, but it arrives later, you confirm/remove the queued sent transaction.

To generalize this out to preventing duplicate `DELETE` and `UPDATE`, you should add a [column of type rowversion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx). Include this value in the `WHERE` clause of all queries, and those queries will affect no rows if someone else has touched the row since you last read it. You still have to detect that no rows were affected and do something intelligent afterward--and this can be very difficult--but at least you have detected and avoided the edit conflict or duplicated action.

If the problem can't be isolated to particular edits to particular rows, then please ask a new question, providing some concrete examples so you can get better suggestions. Throw me a comment with a link to the new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: The timestamp sounds like the best solution, as it is quite possible that everything else in the transaction could be the same.

Comment: revisiting this question... what about the general case where instead of simple inserts there are updates, drops, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some constraints to your fields:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT MyTable UNIQUE (Value1, Value2, Value3)
```